# Total Commander search by regex in filenames only

Tags: search, regex, total-commander

I'm using TC 64 bit 9.0a final, and I want to search file **names** by regular expressions. However, when I check regex, it searches in file contents, too. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I found out that regex search in TC wasn't broken after all. What happened is that I was searching for a lot of optional matches (about 100) at the same time, and some of the matching patterns also existed inside a file. So I thought the regex search was broken.